# Listing all your Github gists on one page?

Tags: github, gist

I have a few Github gists that I am showing off my coding style to potential employers. I do believe all of my github gists are public coz that's how I chose to make em. But upon visiting gist.github.com/myusername ...I get that I have no public gists. I can however view each of my individual gists independently without logging in on there public urls. meaning that they are indeed public gists.

How can I list them all on one page?

Thanks.

Comment: I tried with my gists, they are shown on one page under my id, no matter I'm logged in or not.

Comment: Do they have a lock or smiley face icon in upper right corner?

Answer (score 3):

As @aleung mentioned, you should be able to view all your public gists with a link like:

`https://gist.github.com/{username}`

For example, all of my public ones are viewable here: https://gist.github.com/bcantoni

If it's not working correctly, you could contact [Github Support](https://github.com/contact). I've found them to be very responsive.

Comment: This is a correct answer, yes. But the solution is such an inconvenient way to get that list. Wish there were more tools